# clear error props on form revisit - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a form which contains a few text fields. When the form is submitted and the submission contains errors, they are displayed on the page.

The code is as follows.

```
{this.props.missingFields &&
                <div className="alert alert-danger">
                  <p className="doc-missing-fields" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup(this.props.missingFields)} />
                </div>
              }
```

The reducer is defined as follows.

```
case helpers.actionTypeSuccess(types.ACTION_SUBMIT_DOCUMENT):
      return {
        ...state,
        userEmployeeDocuments : action.result.data.response.userEmployeeDocuments,
        missingFields         : (action.result.data.response.missingKey) ? action.result.data.response.missingKey : '',
        validator             : {}
      };
```

Now the issue is that, the error message is displayed and then i move to some other page and come back to the same form, **the error message is still showing up there.**

I need to clear the errors when the form is visited again.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Clear the `missingFields` from store on `componentWillUnmount`?

Comment: are you saying i need to make another api call to clear the error props?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new action and need to call it in componentWillUnmount
without action dispatch, you cannot change redux state

```js
case helpers.actionTypeSuccess(types.ACTION_CLEAR_SUBMITED_DOCUMENT):
      return {
        ...state,
        userEmployeeDocuments :'',
        missingFields         : '',
        validator             : {}
      };
```